# docker dusk browser can't another web server container

Tags: docker, laravel-5, selenium-chromedriver

set .env like the followings about Server address.

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
APP_DOMAIN=localhost
```

I am using apache2 (docker container) as web server.
under this condition, to test with dusk, started up selenium/standalone-chrome as another container.

```
docker run -p 4444:4444 --name selenium --link apache2:apache2 -d selenium/standalone-chrome
```

to confirm the connection between docker containers, 
used the following commands

```
docker exec -it selenium bash,
cat /etc/hosts/
```

result was
172.17.0.6  apache2 a1c15575e4c8

also confirmed ping apache2 from selenium container.

but from here, couldn't do dusk test using following command.
when I check the browser response, there was no contents.

```
docker exec apache2 php artisan dusk
```

I think setting is wrong. but can't notice it.
could you help?

the following is php source code.

DuskTestCase.php

```
abstract class DuskTestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    /**
     * Prepare for Dusk test execution.
     *
     * @beforeClass
     * @return void
     */
    public static function prepare()
    {
        static::startChromeDriver();
    }

    /**
     * Create the RemoteWebDriver instance.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected function driver()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless'
        ]);
        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://selenium:4444/wd/hub', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
                ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
            )
        );
    }
}
```

ExampleTest.php

```
class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            print_r($browser->visit('/')->resolver->elements);exit;
            $browser->visit('/')
                    ->assertSee('login');
        });
    }
}
```